# Python get the value of PsdHeader Ojbect

Tags: python

I have a `PsdHeader` object, when i print this, object show:-

```
PsdHeader(number_of_channels=4, height=2972, width=2244, depth=8, color_mode=RGB)
```

in terminal. 
I want use the key "height" to get the value 2972, how to do that?

Comment: Please show ypur rest code what have you tried?

Comment: `height = header.height`?

Comment: not work it says 'PSDImage' object has no attribute 'height'

Comment: What do you get if you print `dir(header)` ?

Comment: dir(header) i get ['__add__', ---'count', 'depth', 'height', 'index', 'number_of_channels', 'width']

Comment: suppose you have to assign your object to variable and than access attributes using it

Comment: Yes,it works! foo = psd.header then print foo.height. it works. Thanks all you guys. Thanks micgeronimo!

Comment: In that case `print psd.header.height` would also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i'm new to python, please forgive my stupid and confused question. When i print the PsdHeader object, the result looks like a tuple,(actually it's an object) and i don't know how to get the value of it.in that case, it's wrong to access the height value from psd.header.height. Try to use property access method. And use a tmp variable, i get the height value. `foo = psd.header`,`print foo.height`.